# Long transit at Munich airport—10 hours: Can i go out, and how do I make a reservation for a Napcab or Lounge to sleep?

Tags: airports, layovers, sleeping, munich, muc

I have a 10-hour layover at the Munich airport.

I arrive at 5:15am in Terminal 2, and my other flight departs at 3:40pm from the same Terminal.

My questions are:

1. How long does it take for one to go outside and then get back in?
2. If going out isn't worth it, is there a place I can sleep?

I know there is Napcab but do they need reservations? Are there other options? (Lounges I presume, but I'm travelling in Economy Class).

Comment: With such a long layover it sounds like both flights are extra-Schengen (and your times correspond to a Lufthansa connection Riyadh-Munich-Chicago), which is relevant to how much time you need. In particular, if you want to leave the airport you need either a Schengen visa or a passport from an visa-exempt country. Do you have that?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think an answer should address both Schengen visa and visa-exempt for the sake of other visitors. (Oh hey, *I* will be in MUC tomorrow!)

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes I have valid Schengen. it's Schengen Visa from Italian embassy and I used it to access to France before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you have the right to enter the Schengen area without any additional hassle, 10 hours is more than enough to go to the center, hang out there, even do some sightseeing in case you've never been to Munich before, then return and safely catch your onward flight.

There's a direct [train/s-bahn](http://www.munich-airport.de/en/consumer/anab/bahn/index.jsp) connection to the airport that takes around 40-45 minutes from the center. Getting out of the airport is pretty fast, I assume it would take you around 15-20 minutes on a normal day. Obviously you should reserve more time for security checks and that sort of stuff for entering the airport later on, but 2 hours before your flight departure time is very much on the safe side, you usually need much less than that. If you're 100% cautious, it will still leave you more than 5 hours in central Munich. It's a pretty city, I would recommend visiting in case it's your first time and you have the necessary documents to enter the Schengen area.

Comment: If you are interested in local traditions, many villages around the airport will erect a Maibaum on the 1st of May. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maypole#Germany_and_Austria for general information, http://www.ed-live.de/region_mai and http://www.fs-live.de/region_mai for a list of villages.